# Suma de dos listas en Python

Tags: python, lista, sum

He estado tratando de hacer una función recursiva en Python que devuelva la suma de dos listas, recibiendo la posición en la que se encuentra su ultimo elemento y la propia lista.

Mi intención es la de localizar cual de las dos es la mas grande, y una vez hecho esto ir sumando los elementos de la lista mas corta a la lista mas larga, desde su ultimo elemento hasta el primero.

No se si el fallo esta en la operación de suma porque Python no la soporta, o en alguna otra línea, pero he probado varios cambios y aunque me compila y lo ejecuta correctamente me devuelve un valor None cuando trato de imprimir dicha suma.

Siendo 'a' y 'b' las listas y 'n' y 'm' la posición de su ultimo elemento, respectivamente, el código es :

```
def suma(n, a, m, b):
    if m == 0:
        a[m] = a[m] + b[m]
        return a
    else:
        if n >= m:
            a[m] = a[m] + b[m]
            suma(n, a, m-1, b)
        else:
            suma(m, b, n, a)
```

Comment: Puedes sumar las listas de esta forma `a+b` y te devolverá una nueva lista con todos los elementos de ambas

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes probar de la sigguiente manera, y mejoras la forma en la que se consumiria la funciona de suma ya que es algo engorroso tener que pasar como argumento las longitudes de las listas, Python te ofrece la funcion `len` para facilitar este proceso.

Asi tu funcion recursiva quedaria de la siguiente manera

```
def suma(a, b):
    max_list = a if len(a) > len(b) else b
    min_list = a if len(a) < len(b) else b
    min_len = min(len(a), len(b))

    return suma_recursiva(min_list, max_list, min_len)

def suma_recursiva(min_list, max_list, min_len, index = 0):
    if index == min_len:
        return max_list

    max_list[index] += min_list[index]

    return suma_recursiva(min_list, max_list, min_len, index + 1)

lista_1 = [1, 1, 1, 1]
lista_2 = [1, 1, 1]

res = suma(lista_1, lista_2)

print(res)
```

Utilizando una funcion auxiliar para realizar la recursividad facilitas la estructura, la funcion `suma` se encarga de incializar todos los datos necesarios para que la funcion recursiva pueda funcionar, luego esta llama y retorna el resultado de la funcion recursiva

Answer (score 0):

Puesto que lo que necesitas es ir sumando los valores que va generando la función suma, debes volver a llamarla con un `return suma()` si solo pones `suma()` te devolverá `None`.

Tu códígo está bien salvo por eso, quedaría así:

```
def suma(n, a, m, b):
    if m == 0:
        a[m] = a[m] + b[m]
        return a
    else:
        if n >= m:
            a[m] = a[m] + b[m]
            return suma(n, a, m - 1, b)
        else:
            return suma(m, b, n, a)
```

Si le pasas dos listas para probar:

```
lista_1 = [3, 5, 2, 1]
lista_2 = [2, 3, 1]

lista_suma = suma(3, lista_1, 2, lista_2)
print(lista_suma)
```

Te dará de resultado [5, 8, 3, 1]

**Otra manera sin recursión**

Supongo que el hecho de hacerlo mediante recursión será para aprender a utilizarla, pero te pongo por si acaso otra manera mas corta de hacerlo:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

lista_1 = [3, 5, 2, 1]
lista_2 = [2, 3, 1]

lista_suma = [l1 + l2 for l1, l2 in zip_longest(lista_1, lista_2, fillvalue=0)]
print(lista_suma)
```

Esto también te devolverá [5, 8, 3, 1]